# systemd service failed to start bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, systemd

I am running a bash script as systemd service but it is giving me this error

`Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/pipeline/entity-extraction/start_consumer.sh: Permission denied
Feb  8 11:59:58 irum systemd[1]: ee-consumer.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb  8 11:59:58 irum systemd[1]: Unit ee-consumer.service entered failed state.`

My bash scrip is running 2 Python scripts and it runs fine when I run it from terminal as 
`sudo bash start_consumer.sh`

**start_consumer.sh**

```
while true
do
    echo "starting FIRST Consumer.py : $(date +"%T")"
    python3 /home/irum/Desktop/Marketsyc/Consumer.py &
    pid=$!
    echo "pid:$pid"
    sleep 60

    echo "starting SECOND Consumer.py : $(date +"%T")"
    python3 /home/irum/Desktop/Marketsyc/Consumer.py &
    new_pid=$!
    echo "new_pid:$new_pid"
    # Here I want to kill FIRST Consumer.py
    echo "killing first consumer"
    kill "$pid"
    sleep 60

    # Here I want to kill SECOND Consumer.py
    echo "killing second consumer"
    kill "$new_pid"
done
```

code of my systemd service **ee-consumer.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Entity extraction - consumer
After=default.target
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=pipeline
ExecStart=/home/pipeline/entity-extraction/start_consumer.sh
```

how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux start up script in systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15146049/608639)

Comment: @jww No it's not. I am facing a different problem. Kindly, re read my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `shebang` line and `permission` to the script, for systemd to execute.

Add `#!/bin/bash` to the start of the bash script. And do the following,

```
chmod 755 /home/pipeline/entity-extraction/start_consumer.sh
```

Comment: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/runtime/run/ee-consumer-B.pid'`
Now I am getting this error. That's the file where my Consumer.py script writes PID

Comment: Check the `persmission` on the `/data/runtime/run/` directory. `ls -l /data/runtime/run/`

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 pipeline pipeline 5 Feb  8 12:23 ee-aggregator.pid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     6 Feb  8 10:32 ee-consumer-B.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     6 Feb  8 09:03 ee-consumer.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 pipeline pipeline 6 Feb  8 12:26 ee-dbwriter.pid`
both consumer's pid files has root permission

Comment: Okay. The problem is you have not specified which user should be used to run this bash script. Put `User=root` after the line `[Service]` in the `ee-consumer.service` file